# How to display additional readonly view data in Edit view MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I have a View that handles the Edit action for editing a weekly update on your weight and nutrition. Editing a singular model is all good. I am using EditorFor to create the fields.

My problem is that I want to also display a read only version of last week's results as a guide but I would like to use DisplayFor so that it formats bools to be disabled checkboxes and formats the dates based on my formatting in the model. I added the model to the Viewbag and tried to access it by using @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.BodyWeight, (myproject.Models.WeeklyReport)ViewBag.LastReport) however it just brings up the data in the model that I sent to the view and not the Viewbag data. What is the best method to display this kind of data while keeping the constraints/formatting of the model intact?

Thanks.

View

```
@model myproject.Models.WeeklyReport

<h2>Weekly Report - Week 1</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table class="weeklyreport">
        <tr>
            <th>Week</th>
            <td class="result-bold">Goals</td>
            <td>Current Week</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Body Weight</th>
            <td class="result-bold">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.BodyWeight, (myproject.Models.WeeklyReport)ViewBag.Goals)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BodyWeight)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BodyWeight)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Diary Reviewed</th>
            <td class="result-bold">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DiaryReviewed, (myproject.Models.WeeklyReport)ViewBag.Goals)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DiaryReviewed)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DiaryReviewed)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    WeeklyReport goal = new WeeklyReport()
    {  
        BodyWeight = 60,
        DiaryReviewed = true
    };

    WeeklyReport rpt = new WeeklyReport()
    {
        BodyWeight = 68,
        DiaryReviewed = false

    };
    ViewBag.LastReport = goal;
    return View(rpt);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a viewmodels or partialViews and pass the viewbag item to the partial.

An example of viewmodel usage

```
 public class WeeklyReportViewModel
    {
      public WeeklyReport LastReport { get; set; }
      public WeeklyReport Report { get; set; }
    }
```

combine the reports

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  WeeklyReport goal = new WeeklyReport()
  {  
    BodyWeight = 60,
    DiaryReviewed = true
  };

  WeeklyReport rpt = new WeeklyReport()
  {
    BodyWeight = 68,
    DiaryReviewed = false

  };

  WeeklyReportViewModel viewmodel = new WeeklyReportViewModel()
  {
    LastReport = goal,
    ActualReport = rpt
  }

  return View(viewmodel);
```

}

In the view

```
@model myproject.ViewModels.WeeklyReportViewModel 

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.LastReport.BodyWeight)
```